# How to add Today Widget Chevron

Tags: ios, ios-extensions

I am working on an app with a Today Widget extension. I've seen some widgets, including a sample app from Apple, that display a chevron in the top right to take the user to the app. I've looked through the documentation and sample code and can't figure out how this is added.

The sample app that's downloaded from here has it, but there isn't any information about how to enable it. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/notificationcenter/building_a_simple_widget_for_the_today_view

Does anyone know how to enable this?

[image: sample today widget]

Comment: I've never worked with extensions before, but it looks like that's not what the chevron does? It seems to expand/contract the widget's size, not take the user to the app. And it looks like you can get the chevron to show up using `extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = .expanded` in the extension view controller (which is in the sample code you provided – if you comment that line out, the chevron goes away and you can't expand the widget).

Comment: Oh, you are correct!

Answer (score 2):

You can add the chevron button to your widget by setting the `widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode` of your extension context to `.expanded`:

```
extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = .expanded
```

(Note that the chevron button does not take you to the app, but rather it toggles between expanded/compact sizes of your widget.)